# Entry to lounges at Addis Ababa airport?

Tags: lounges, ethiopia

I have an eight hour layover at Addis Ababa airport and none of the tickets (Cloud Nine etc.) that would immediately qualify for entry to the lounges I found there. Is it possible to buy a "day pass" or the like when arriving there?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Loungebuddy](https://www.loungebuddy.com/ADD), there are four lounges (the ShebaMiles lounge, Star Alliance lounge, Cloud Nine lounge 1, and Cloud Nine lounge 2).

However all of them are "reserved for passengers with specific credentials such as elite status, premium tickets, or other access methods that are required for entry.", and as such, you cannot purchase entry into them.

Comment: 4?  I believe there are actually 3.  Having been in 2 of them, about the only praise I can give them is that they are certainly better than sitting in the rest of the terminal...

Comment: @Doc see link? I mean I've not been there, but it names the ShebaMiles lounge, Star Alliance lounge, Cloud Nine lounge 1, and Cloud Nine lounge 2.